# MYSQL multiple words search result

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

When I type about three keywords or more it seems to only search the first keyword i.e bolt nut washer it will only search bolt.
I would like to search multiple keywords or the complete search term when inputted.

This is the code:

```
if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) {
    $pagenum = 1;
} else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
}
$page_limit = ($_GET["show"] <> "" && is_numeric($_GET["show"]) ) ? $_GET["show"] : 8;

try {
    $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
    if ($keyword <> "" ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
. " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR contact_no1 LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 ORDER BY first_name ";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $total_count = count($stmt->fetchAll());
    $last = ceil($total_count / $page_limit);

    if ($pagenum < 1) {
        num < 1) {
    } elseif ($pagenum > $last) {
        $pagenum = $last;
    }
    $lower_limit = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_limit;
    $lower_limit = ($lower_limit < 0) ? 0 : $lower_limit;
    $sql2 = $sql . " limit " . ($lower_limit) . " ,  " . ($page_limit) . " ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql2);

    if ($keyword <> "" ) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Fixed by changing:

```
. " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR contact_no1 LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name ";
```

to

```
. " (first_name LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR contact_no1 LIKE '%".$keyword."%') ORDER BY last_name DESC ";
```

Now the search returns any keyword entered